# AS3 RegExp to match words with boundry type characters in them

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3, word-boundary

I'm wanting to match a list of words which is easy enough when those words are truly words. For example `/\b (pop|push) \b/gsx` when ran against the string

> pop gave the door a push but it popped back

will match the words pop and push but not popped.

I need similar functionality for words that contain characters that would normally qualify as word boundaries. So I need `/\b (reverse!|push) \b/gsx` when ran against the string

> push reverse! reverse!push

to only match reverse! and push but not match reverse!push. Obviously this regex isn't going to do that so what do I need to use instead of \b to make my regex smart enough to handle these funky requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of a word, \b means "the previous character was a word character, and the next character (if there is a next character) is not a word character.  You want to drop the first condition because there might be a non-word character at the end of the "word".  That leaves you with a negative lookahead:

```
/\b (reverse!|push) (?!\w)/gx
```

I'm pretty sure AS3 regexes support lookahead.

Comment: In addition to using (?!\w) as the trailing \b replacement I also used (?<!\w) as the leading \b replacement that way words that start with special characters like $! would be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you need three (possibly four) cases in your alternation, not two.

- `/\breverse!(?:\s|$)/` reverse! by itself
- `/\bpush\b/` push by itself
- `/\breverse!push\b/` together
- `/\bpushreverse!(?:\s|$)/` this is the possible case

Your second problem is that a `\b` won't match after a `"!"` because it is not a `\w`.  Here is what [Perl 5 has to say about `\b`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), you may want to consult your docs to see if they agree:

> A word boundary ("\b") is a spot between two characters that has a "\w" on one side of it and a "\W" on the other side of it (in either order), counting the imaginary characters off the beginning and end of the string as matching a "\W".  (Within character classes "\b" represents backspace rather than a word boundary, just as it normally does in any double-quoted string.)

So, the regex that you need is something like

```
/ \b ( reverse!push | reverse! | push ) (?: \s | \b | $ )+ /gx;
```

I left out the `/s` because there are not periods in this regex, so treat as single line makes no sense.  If `/s` doesn't mean treat as a single line in your engine you should probably add it back.  Also, you should read up on how your engine handles alternation.  I know in Perl 5 to get the right behaviour you must arrange the items this way (otherwise reverse! would always win over reverse!push).

Comment: Read the question again, Chas; the OP *doesn't* want to match "reverse!push".

Answer (score 0):

You can replace \b by something equivalent, but less strict:

```
/(?<=\s|^)(reverse!|push)(?=\s|$)/g
```

This way the limiting factor of the `\b` (that it can only match before or after an actual `\w` word character) is removed.

Now white space or the start/end of the string function as valid separators, and the inner expression can be easily built at run-time, from a list of search terms for example.